# Can a digipot be used between an amp and speaker for volume control

Tags: arduino

Maybe someone can help me with this question.

Can I use a digipot (controlled by an Arduino) between a car radio (ISO pin) and a speaker to control it's volume (fading)?

Comment: Some of them yes.

Comment: Indeed it seems possible, but your question is not detailed enough to give a full answer.

Comment: Consider 1kohm as minimum

Comment: For typical 8-ohm loudspeakers, good quality audio results from driving with an ideal voltage source (having near-zero internal resistance). Adding an intervening resistor degrades audio quality for discerning listeners.

Comment: It would only be used to fade out after ignition off, quality of the sound would not matter too much. Btw. 50W max

Comment: Give 0.1" is the silicon area of a digipot, with thermal resistance of 200 degree Centrigrade per watt, and the tiny internal resistive segments being even smaller and thus more vulnerable, I'd say no ---- unless you are talking 10 milliWatt attenuation tasks.

Answer (score 5):

Generally no.

Digital potentiometers are designed for signal levels and powers. Your amplifier output is much too powerful for this and the currents involved driving a loudspeaker will be too high for a digital potentiometer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHUw6a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Standard configuration for volume control is to put the potentiometer - digital or analog - in the signal line before the power amplifier.*

Comment: I know that this is the right way to do it, thank you for your answer though. People used D Pads in earlier days, so I thought maybe.